# Get most recent row inserted with the least specificity

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'll first explain the data model then the desired results and what I have tried.

I have `vehicles` and `sales` tables:

```
CREATE TABLE VEHICLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    BRAND INT NOT NULL,
    MODEL VARCHAR(255),
    VERSION VARCHAR(255),

    UNIQUE(BRAND, MODEL, VERSION),
    FOREIGN KEY(BRAND) REFERENCES BRAND(ID)
)

CREATE TABLE SALES 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    VEHICLE_ID INT NOT NULL,
    DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    SALE INT NOT NULL,
    CREATED_DATE DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),

    FOREIGN KEY (VEHICLE_ID) REFERENCES VEHICLE(ID)
)
```

This way I can insert several entries for the same vehicle for the same date (when I want to update, I insert a new row)

```
INSERT INTO SALES (VEHICLE_ID, DATE, SALE, USER_ID)   
VALUES (1, '2018-01-01', 2, 3) -- then later i update by inserting a new row
       (1, '2018-01-01', 4, 3)
```

I want to retrieve the last sale inserted for a specific date range (using the DATE), then filter for a specific BRAND, or model or version.

I got it working by doing this

```
SELECT 
    S.DATE AS date, SUM(S.SALE_PROJECTION) AS saleProjection
FROM 
    SALE_PROJECTION S,
    (SELECT MAX(ID) AS id 
     FROM SALE_PROJECTION 
     WHERE DATE >= CAST(@dateStart AS DATE) 
       AND DATE <= CAST(@dateEnd AS DATE) 
     GROUP BY DATE, VEHICLE_ID) S_M,
    VEHICLE V
WHERE 
    1 = 1
    AND S.ID = S_M.ID
    AND S.VEHICLE_ID = V.ID
    AND V.BRAND = 1
    AND V.MODEL = 'A6'
    AND V.VERSION = '1.0'
GROUP BY S.DATE
ORDER BY DATE
```

The problem is i want to get the sales for the brand 1 that has the least specificity, meaning: 
If i have 3 vehicles:

```
(1, 'A3', '1.0'),
(1, 'A3', '2.0'),
(1, 'A3', null),
(1, null, null);
```

- if i insert a sale (1, 2018-01-01, 2, 3)
- if i insert a sale (2, 2018-01-01, 3, 3) -- the sum for 2018-01-01 would be 5
- but then insert a sale for (2, 2018-01-01, 3, 3) -- the sum for 2018-01-01 has to be 3, because it's the last inserted with the least specifity

But the oposite must be true as well

- if i insert a sale (3, 2018-01-01, 4, 3)
- then insert a sale for (1, 2018-01-01, 1, 3)
- then insert a sale for (2, 2018-01-01, 1, 3)
- the sum for 2018-01-01 has to be 2, because it's the last inserted

The most general combination of Brand, Model, Version has to "hide" the most specific.

Do i need to change my data model? or this is possible?
I can give more examples if needed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: What do the columns of the 4 records after "If I have 3 vehicles" mean?

Comment: @WolfgangKais those 4 records are Vehicle inserts, the first 2 are specific(brand + model + version) and the other 2 is just insert the model, and the last is just the brand

Comment: So still these are 4 records, not 3, and they don't have a `VEHICLE_ID`. You introduced a table `SALES` but not `SALE_PROJECTION`. I don't see any difference between (2, 2018-01-01, 3, 3) and (2, 2018-01-01, 3, 3), and it's unclear why two records should summed and a third one should not. Please explain the "least specific" condition looking at your sample data. How can both criteria ("last inserted" and "least specific") be used together to identify the desired records? How can two records at the same time be "last inserted"?

Comment: Think there is a typo, pretty sure the vehicle id in the first example should be 1,2,3 not 1,2,2

Comment: Trying to read into this - looking at you last two examples - in the first you have a version row being superseded by a model row, and in the second you have a model row being superseded by a version row. I don't see anything about "less specific" taking precedence, just whatever the "specificity" of the last sale  being the driver for whatever you are summing.

Comment: You have a statement: "INSERT INTO SALES (VEHICLE_ID, DATE, SALE, USER_ID)"  but the table definition for SALES does not include a field USER_ID